# How to read session history currently in memory (the history that eventually gets written to ".bash_history" upon logout

Tags: linux, bash, centos, rhel, linux-kernel

I've encountered this issue several times where I need to access the history of a currently active session.  Unless there is an easier way, I'm about to write a C program to read this from a target session.

**Does anyone know where in memory the session history is saved for a bash session?**  Is this saved under an environment variable or somewhere in /proc?  I've searched everywhere for this and the closest answer I am able to find is "somewhere in memory".   Understandably, the system can be configured to make the session history get written every time someone executes a command however this is not practical for my particular use (if I could run the "history -a" command as another active session then that may suffice).

If anyone has any constructive hints or direction as to where to find this or where to find the starting memory address (for a given session/TTY) which would contain this info.

Please keep in mind this isn't a duplicate of a typical history question asking how to store a current history session to memory or how to configure bash to store it right away (the internet and this forum are full of those already :) ).

This is asking how to get the current "in memory history" for other sessions also logged in as root (or another user).

Thanks for your help,

Jeff

Comment: If your system is appropriately configured with ASLR, it won't be at a fixed address, and in any event, this solution is going to be brittle and prone to breakage if bash ever gets updated.  It's also possible to exclude commands from history.  Explaining more about why you need this information might help us come up with a better solution.

Comment: I need this information as I work linux servers.  By the time I get called in, other people are already logged into the servers and who knows what commands they have ran.   Once I login, I can see all of the commands currently in history however I can't see the commands for the bash sessions which are still logged in.  I need to know if the bash sessions currently logged in have performed commands which would have created the issue I am investigating.  These users are not trying to be malicious but may have performed commands on accident which have caused problems.

Comment: You are better off setting `HISTSIZE` to `-1` in `/etc/profile.d` if the shell is bash or installing an auditing framework on those servers.  Trying to pull it out of memory is going to be a disaster, and if you make a mistake, you'll crash the shell.

Answer (score 0):

`history -a FILE` saves the history *since the last run of `history -a`* to `FILE`, and `history -r FILE` loads the contents of `FILE` into the in-memory history. Let's try using this in a shell with default configuration:

```
$ PS1='parent\$ ' bash --noprofile --norc
```

Now let's empty out the custom history file we're going to use and the default Bash history file:

```
parent$ > history.txt
parent$ > ~/.bash_history
```

Then we start *another* subshell to demonstrate saving and loading history:

```
parent$ PS1='child\$ ' bash --noprofile --norc
```

Then run a command:

```
child$ echo foo
foo
```

Save the history to a given file:

```
child$ history -a history.txt
```

Append the history to the default file:

```
child$ cat history.txt >> ~/.bash_history
```

Exit the shell:

```
child$ exit
exit
```

Verify that the custom history file contains what we expect:

```
parent$ cat history.txt
echo foo
history -a history.txt
```

Verify that the Bash history file contains what we expect:

```
parent$ cat ~/.bash_history
echo foo
history -a history.txt
cat history.txt >> ~/.bash_history
exit
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I think your solution shows how to store a current history session to memory.  It looks like the solution provided only works on the currently logged in session.  Lets say that I have 4 active ssh connections to a server (pts/0, pts/1, pts/2, and pts/3).  Each of these sessions is currently active.  I happened to log into pst/3.  Each of these sessions has  "in-memory history" as you have referenced in your update.

Comment: There are ways to modify the ps to make it write out the commands to the file history each time a command is run however this causes problems when multiple sessions are performing commands at the same time.  My goal is to determine where is the "in-memory history" for each of these sessions being stored so I can try and read it myself from the target session of my choice.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with the "history" command alone.  So I was going to make a C program that can get this information on other active sessions.

Comment: I would suggest updating your question with this information, so others have a chance of answering it.